# How to do binding for drop down and checkbox in App Maker?

Tags: binding, google-app-maker

From the screenshot of my form:

[image]

1. How to do the binding to Contract Type from dropdown list option or if user key in input in the label next to it if the option is not listed in the drop-down?
2. How to do binding for the checkbox option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Dropdown-Input` combo I would go with two model fields: `ContractType` and `CustomContractType`. For the `ContractType` I would specify `possibleValues` (Type One, Type Two, Type Three, ..., Other) in advanced field settings and bind them to `Dropdown`'s options:

```
@models.ModelName.fields.ContractType.possibleValues
```

and bind value to `ContractType` field:

```
@datasource.item.ContractType
```

Then I would bind `visible` or `enabled` `Input`'s property to

```
@datasource.item.ContractType === 'Other'
```

and bind value to `CustomContractType` field:

```
@datasource.item.CustomContractType
```

and enforce this logic in `onBeforeCreate` and `onBeforeSave` model events:

```js
if (record.ContractType !== 'Other' && record.CustomContractType !== null) {
  record.CustomContractType = null; // or throw exception...
}

if (record.ContractType === 'Other' && record.CustomContractType === null) {
  throw new Error('CustomContractType is required');
}
```

---

**Renewal notice(notices?)**

In case you need to select only one renewal notice, I would recommend to use `Radio Group` widget. Otherwise you can keep using multiple checkboxes and introduce multiple model fields for each checkbox **OR** use `Multiselect` select widget and try to mate it with string model's field in combination with [split](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/transformers#split) binding transformer (you can find sample in [Document Approval](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval/) template, Admin/Settings page).

Comment: ouh nice tips, but can I do like if I choose "other", the contractType field  will take the value from customContract field? can two widget bind to same datasource.item.customContract?

Comment: You can bind any number of widgets to the same field.

Comment: won't it be redundant? or data source will capture the latest one? for example checkbox1 with value = 5 then checkbox2 with value =10, but both widget value direct to same datasource.item.checkboxValue ..

Comment: Checkbox's value can only be bound to boolean value, which can only be `true` or `false`.

Comment: How to enable checkbox such as the one in Google form?